# Remove XML Node With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, delete-row

I wonder whether someone may be able yo help me please.

I've put together [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/deletetest.php) page which allows users to view a gallery of their uploaded images.

Upon initial upload, the physical images are saved in the following file structure:
`UploadedFiles/userid/locationid/image` and the details of the image i.e. description etc are saved in an xml file called `files.xml` which is in the same directory as the physical images.

I'm now working on allowing the user to be able to delete these images.

By way of a deletion icon under each image, I've, admitedly with some help, put together the following which successfully deletes the physical image.

'Deletion Icon Onclick Event'

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    Galleria.ready(function() {
        this.$('thumblink').click();

    $(".galleria-image").append( 
    "<span class='btn-delete ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>"); 
    $(".btn-delete").live("click", function(){
    var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img"); 

    // send the AJAX request
    $.ajax({
    url : 'delete.php',
    type : 'post',
    data : { image : img.attr('src') },
    success : function(){
    alert('Deleting image... ');
    img.parent().fadeOut('slow');
    }
    });

    return false;
    });

    });

</script>
```

Original 'delete.php'

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST)) {
$image = $_POST['image'];

if (file_exists($image)) {
unlink($image);
} 
}
?>
```

**Updated 'delete.php'**

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST)) {
$image = $_POST['image'];

if (file_exists($image)) {
unlink($image);
} 
}

$doc = new DOMDocument; 
$doc->load('files.xml'); 

$thedocument = $doc->documentElement; 

$list = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('files'); 

$nodeToRemove = null; 
foreach ($list as $domElement){ 
$attrValue = $domElement->getAttribute('file_name'); 
if ($attrValue == 'image') { 
$nodeToRemove = $domElement;
} 
} 

if ($nodeToRemove != null) 
$thedocument->removeChild($nodeToRemove); 

echo $doc->saveXML(); 
?>
```

The problem I'm having is deleting the xml node form the xml file. I've provided an extract of the XML file below.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <files>
  <file name="stag.jpg" source="stag.jpg" size="21341" originalname="stag.jpg" description="No description provided" userid="1" locationid="1" /> 
  </files>
```

I've done quite a bit of research about how to go about this and found that jQuery had it's own command i.e. `jQuery.remove` which I thought would be able to delete the node. Following the brief tutorial I added the following to the end of my 'Onclick Event' script:

```
var doc = $(files.xml);
doc.find('file_name:src').remove();
```

Unfortunately, although I don't receive a specific error, the node isn't being deleted from the file. I'm a complete beginner when it comes to XML so perhaps I'm looking at this too simplistically.

I just wondered wheteher someone could perhaps have a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks and regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because JavaScript(JQuery) loads the XML DOM in memory and then when you delete a node,
it gets deleted from the in-memory xml doc(the object).

It wont be removed from the physical XML file.

JS runs in a sandbox Browser environment and cannot alter local files on the system.
and if you are trying to load xml from a remote server then its a very bad idea.

the XML file from remote server is downloaded as temp file and then when you load XML again an in-memory DOM is created and the node is deleted from it.

So in case you want the actual file to be changed,
you will need to use AJAX and send some HTTP request to your server to do the same to the physical file.

**UPDATE**:

Check this tutorial 
http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-XML-Removing-Node-P415.html

and try to load the xml file in your delete.php and remove the corresponding node from it and then save this xml back to the original file which will be overwritten.

Comment: Hi @Amogh Talpallikar, many thanks for taking the time to reply to my post. I'm really very new to this element of programming, I just wondered whether you could possibly elborate on this please, so that I know where I need to start from. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: You will have to use delete.php to delete the node from the xml file.
whenever you delete the physical image , you will have to delete the its node from XML.

Comment: Checkout PHP XML DOM manipulation, load the xml dom using PHP then remove the node from it and save it back.

Comment: Hi, sincere thanks for the guidance and link. I've been reading about how to delete nodes since my post yesterady and I've put a script together combining my original delete script and the deltion of the node. The problem I'm having is that I can delete the physical image but not the related node in the XML. As I said earlier, I'm very new to this element of programming, so perhaps I'm making basic mistakes. I've added my updated script to my original post. I just wondered whether you could perhaps have a look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong. Many thanks and regards.

Comment: I cant write the exact code here because it has been some time I have touched PHP I am more into iOS dev these days.
But to be precise.
You are doing fine there but here are few mistakes.
now loop thru the nodes,
find the correct file-name attribute and match the name with passed in as parameter.
now delete that node and save the data to the same xml file.
Make sure you are using the correct paths.

Comment: In your code , the attribute name is  'file_name' and I dont see an attribute with that name in your sample xml file.
also $attrValue is a node  object not a string, it wont be equal to 'image' if thats what u r trying, it should be having a value property or something similar which should be equal to image.
be patient read more on php xml manipulation and try to understand the basics.
Dont just guess things and do anything , keep reading the manual for functions you use. :)