# Remove XML Child Node

Tags: php, xml, xmldom

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using [this](http://www.mapmyfinds.co.uk/development/deletetest.php#/0) page to allow users to view a gallery of their uploaded images.

Upon upload, the images are saved in this filepath `UploadedFiles/userid/locationid/image` and the details of the image i.e. name, description etc are saved in an XML file called `files.xml` which located in the same directory as the images. An extract of this is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <files>
  <file name="AC-0003749-Clark_145520.jpg" source="AC-0003749-Clark_145520.jpg" size="3873" originalname="AC-0003749-Clark_145520.jpg" description="No description provided" userid="1" locationid="1" /> 
  </files>
```

The gallery gives additional functionality to the user by, via the icon under each image, the ability to delete each image. This is done via the following code:

**Icon click Event**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        Galleria.ready(function() {
            this.$('thumblink').click();

        $(".galleria-image").append( 
        "<span class='btn-delete ui-icon ui-icon-trash'></span>"); 
        $(".btn-delete").live("click", function(){
        var img = $(this).closest(".galleria-image").find("img"); 

        // send the AJAX request
        $.ajax({
        url : 'delete.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : { image : img.attr('src') },
        success : function(){
        alert('Deleting image... ');
        img.parent().fadeOut('slow');
        }
        });

        return false;
        });

        });

    </script>
```

**delete.php - Amended Code**

```
<?php 

if (!empty($_POST)) { 
$image = $_POST['image']; 

if (file_exists($image)) { 
unlink($image); 
} 
} 

$doc = new DOMDocument; 
$doc->load('files.xml'); 

$thedocument = $doc->documentElement; 

$list = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('files'); 

$nodeToRemove = null; 
foreach ($list as $domElement){ 
if ($attrValue == '$image') {     $domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement); } 
}

if ($nodeToRemove != null) 
$thedocument->removeChild($nodeToRemove); 

echo $doc->saveXML(); 
?>
```

The deletion of the physical image works fine, but I'm having great difficulty in working out how to delete the relevant child node. Although I receive no error message the node is not deleted. I have received some guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552309/remove-xml-node-with-jquery) from this site about how to go about this, i.e. via PHP XML DOM, but to be honest the more I read about this, the more I get confused. I just can't seem to get my head around it.

I just wondered whether someone could have a look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a node that was found with `getElementsByTagName` you can use the following to remove it:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) { 
    $image = $_POST['image']; 

    if (file_exists($image)) { 
        unlink($image); 
    }

    $doc = new DOMDocument; 
    $doc->load('files.xml');

    // iterate over all tags named <file>
    $list = $doc->getElementsByTagName('file');
    foreach ($list as $domElement) {
        // check whether attribute 'source' equals $image
        if ($domElement->getAttribute('source') == $image) {
            // remove the node
            $domElement->parentNode->removeChild($domElement);
        } 
    }

    echo $doc->saveXML();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jack, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. Forgive me for asking, could you perhaps elaborate as to which lines I should remove to replace with your suggestion please. As I said, I'm really very new to dealing with XML files. Kind regards and thanks

Comment: Hi, thank you for your continued help with this it is greatly appreciated. Unfortunately though, and I'm sure it's me that's doing something wrong, I can't get the node to delete from the XML file. I've updated my original post with my amended code. I just wondered whether you could possibly have a look at this please to see where I've gone wrong. Sincere thanks and regards

Comment: @IRHM Updated the answer again, I should remind you that doing `unlink()` based on a posted variable such as `$image` without checking its value is kinda dangerous ... reader's exercise.

Comment: Hi @Jack, sincere thanks for your help with this. I've noted your warning. I do intend to put a check in for the value, once I've got the node deletion sorted out. I've tried the code, but unfortunately it doesn't delete the relevant node from the XML files. May I just check with you please, does the 'delete.php' file need to be in the same location as the XML file? just a thought. Thanks and kind regards

Comment: @IRHM in the same folder yes, otherwise it won't know where to load "files.xml" from ... btw, I would recommend adding `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); at the top of your script.

Comment: Hi @Jack, thank you for replying so quickly. I think that the location could be the problem. The issue I have is that `files.xml` file is pertient to the `userid` and `locationid`, vales of which are used to create the folders in my folder structure i.e. `UploadedFiles/userid/locationid/files.xml`. The delete.php file is at the very top level so before `UploadedFiles`. I think I'll have to play around with trying to pass the session variables of the 'userid' and 'locationid' to the 'delete.php' file. Many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: @IRHM okay, but being able to read the file was something I already assumed. If the XML echoes to screen, you were able to read it. Mind you that `->saveXML()` doesn't write back to the file.

Comment: Hi @Jack, unfortunately when I run the 'delete.php' script there is no xml output shiown, I think that's part of the problem. I can't see what's happening. I think I'm going to have to spend some time looking at this. Many thanks for all your help and patience. Kind regards

Comment: I would suggest adding `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` at the top of your code then. It should give you a good idea where to look.

Comment: Hi @Jack, many thanks for this. Your time and trouble are greatly appreciated. Kind regards